# numpy: найти значение в массиве, которое повторяется чаще всего

Tags: python, numpy

Нужно решить с numpy.

Создать массив случайных чисел. Найти значение, которое повторяется в массиве чаще всего.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random

size = (int(input("Vvedite razmer massiva: ")))
array = np.random.randint(0,10,size)
print(array)
most_common = 0
count_most_common = 0

for i in range(size):
```

пока все, что смог написать

Comment: В заголовке должно быть краткое описание проблемы, а не автобиография.

Answer (score 3):

используйте методы `unique` и `argmax`:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.randint(-5, 5, 10)
vals, counts = np.unique(arr, return_counts=True)
print(vals[np.argmax(counts)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 import numpy as np
 import numpy.random

 size = (int(input("Vvedite razmer 
       massiva: ")))
 array = [np.random.randint(0,10) for i 
          in range(size)]
 print(array)



 def find_repeat(array):
    max_repeat = 0
    sum_repeat = 0
    value = 0   
    for i in range (size):
        for j in range(size):
           if array[i] == array[j]:
              sum_repeat +=1
           if sum_repeat >= max_repeat:
              max_repeat=sum_repeat
              value=array[i]
   return value

 print(find_repeat(array))
```